# $(document).ready called twice in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, document-ready

This only happens in IE9, i didn't see this behavior in Firefox/Chrome.

the problemetic website is: 
[www.pocomaru.com](http://www.pocomaru.com)

If you open it, set a break point in `$(document).ready`, you will see it comes in there twice when ever the page is loaded, and the first time the `dom` is not ready. `($("createPassLB")` returns invalid.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If possible, can you move your script to the bottom of the page? This ensures the DOM has loaded anyway, so `$(document).ready(..)` just becomes a bit of extra security.

Answer (score 1):

What version of jquery are you using? Version 1.8.0 has a bug similar to what you describe. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282

Comment: I changed to jquery 1.8.3( latest version) but still see the same behavior

Comment: I found this forum [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1821304.aspx/1?Safari+IE9+fires+Page+twice) where the user mentions moving the script code from the bottom of the page to inside the header to fix IE9. It could be worth a shot. If that doesn't work, we may need to see your code.

Comment: I am not sure its called lucky or not.. I removed the facebook js async load script, and then put them back again(the same position) now the page seems to only fire once..

Comment: ok. now it seems related to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282 as I am sure that the second call to document.ready is caused by the failed first call to document ready(). I can see invalid calling object when calling document.ready. In the link, it claims that this issue has been fixed, but I switch to latest jquery, still have the same issue.

Comment: @user648922 - If you are able to recreate the problem in a simple example, you should report it to the jquery folks. You may actually find your problem while trying to create the example.